# Error creating API Gateway Domain Name by terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the terraform definition:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "apigatewatDomainName" {
  domain_name              = servername.companyname.com
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:12345566:certificate/dddddd-3333-4444-5555 0123456789a"
}
```

When I apply the terraform I am getting the error:

**Error: Error creating API Gateway Domain Name: BadRequestException: The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add.**

When I apply the command

```
aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn <certificate-arn>
```

I am getting in the description

```
"DomainValidationOptions": [
        {
            "ValidationStatus": "SUCCESS",
            "ResourceRecord": {
                "Type": "CNAME",
                "Name": "_88f0a9b77497411fd26c281d7d61fbd9.servername.companyname.com",
                "Value": "_4cee246cb2515f9a0c1f101edaee900e.hkvuiqjoua.acm-validations.aws."
            },
            "ValidationDomain": "*.servername.companyname.com",
            "ValidationMethod": "DNS",
            "DomainName": "*.servername.companyname.com"
        }
    ], 

Also, in this description I see

"SubjectAlternativeNames": [
        "*.servername.companyname.com"
    ],
```

So, I assume that I can create a domain like “aaa.servername.companyname.com”,  so I specified 
resource

```
"aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "aaa.servername.companyname.com" {
```

But terraform does not allow to have dots in a resource name, I see the error

“A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.”

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your domain `servername.companyname.com` is not covered by a ACM certificate issued for for `*.servername.companyname.com`.

About wildcard names from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html):

> When you request a wildcard certificate, the asterisk (*) must be in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only one subdomain level. For example, *.example.com can protect login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect test.login.example.com. Also note that *.example.com protects **only the subdomains** of example.com, it **does not protect the bare** or apex domain (example.com).

Also from the same docs:

> However, you can request a certificate that protects a bare or apex domain and its subdomains by specifying **multiple domain names** in your request. For example, you can request a certificate that protects example.com and *.example.com

Comment: I think that the certificate covers the *.servername.companyname.com. The problem is that I cannot specify the aa.servername.companyname.com in the terraform name

Comment: @Alex For `aws_api_gateway_domain_name` you use `servername.companyname.com` domain. Which, according to docs, is not covered by `*.servername.companyname.com`, explaining your error message: "certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover".